# GridView CustomGrid Adapter repeats items

Tags: android

Hey i'm using gridView to show my items. Everything is ok but after six items or scroll some items get repeated.

So i think i have something to do in case the convertItem is not null. But how i load next items

Some short code:

```
 public CustomGridAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Event> finalResult, double latitude, double longitude) {

    this.posLatitude = latitude;
    this.posLongitude = longitude;

    this.context = context;
    this.gridValues = finalResult;
    this.app = new Application(context);
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return gridValues.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // LayoutInflator to call external grid_item.xml file
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        gridView = new View(context);

        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);

        event = gridValues.get(position);

    } else {
        gridView = convertView;
    }
    return gridView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ConvertView is by definition being reused. Make sure to change the values of the view item inflating or setting it.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

// LayoutInflator to call external grid_item.xml file
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View gridView;

if (convertView == null) {

    gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);

} else {
    gridView = convertView;
}

event = gridValues.get(position);
// TODO: set view values based on this event

return gridView;
}
```

Comment: nope when i set event_name = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.name); event_name.setText(event.Name); i get wrong view

Comment: Will need a more complete view of your code to answer further.